# Will a 76-year-old with valid USA driving license be allowed to drive a rented vehicle in Brazil?

Tags: car-rentals, brazil, age-limits

I am 76 years of age and have a valid driving license in the USA.  Will I be able to drive (a rented vehicle) while in Brazil?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your drive license is valid here and according to our laws there is no age limit to drive a car here, when - of course - you are able to do it properly.

Also checking the biggest brazilian car rentals website, I found this:

> **What do I need in order to rent a car from Localiza?**
>
> The minimum requirements to rent a car from us are:
>
> - You must be at least 21 years old;
> - You must have had your driver’s license for at least two years;
> - Subject to credit approval.
>
> If you have a credit card, you can be approved immediately.

Source: https://www.localiza.com/brasil/en-us/faq